# Push to Firebase - Slow and Inconsistent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I have problems with passing data to Firebase from a Chrome extension.
Sometimes it will do it, and sometimes it just won't. Sometimes the data comes after a minute.

Let's say I have the following:

```
function hello() {

  var fbase = new Firebase('https://myurl.firebaseio.com/');

  fbase.set({ first: 'foo', last: 'bar' });
}
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

When I reload my app, and click on my button with id `clickme`, this does get triggered once. Then I change foo and bar to something else, reload the extension, and it doesn't do anything. Does anyone know this? Does firebase ignores me if I push to often? Also tried the `fbase.push` command, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what was wrong:
I was using a very old version of the firebase.js file by accident. Changed the src link to the newest version, now works flawless fast and consistent.

Comment: are you sure, this isssue exist in latest sdk too

Comment: @rashidnk Yes I am pretty sure. No problems at this moment.

Comment: npm -v firebase
4.1.2

Comment: imusing this for ionic project , angularfire2, push() sometime does not work or takes more 10 minutes

Comment: @rashidnk Not familiar with angularfire. If no one can help you, you can contact firebase support directly.